# Como puedo obtener la ruta activa angular si use "router.navigate"

Tags: angular, angular-material

hola tengo actualmente un tree de material de angular en el cual en un `li` tengo un metodo que me permite navegar entre las paginas con `this.router.navigate` entonces quiero obtener la ruta activa para poner sombrearla y cambiarle el color `[routerLinkActive]` no funciona en mi etiqueta `li` este es mi html :

```
   <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
          <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item>
          <li class="mat-tree-node" (click)="navigationPath(node)" routerLinkActive="activo">

            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
            {{node.name}}
          </li>
            </mat-list-item>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-tree-node>
```

la clase activo se la di para cambiar los estilos con css y en mi ts el metodo es este:

```
  navigationPath(node) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(node.path);
    console.log(node.path);
  }
```

lo que quiero es obtener la ruta activa para cambiandole el background donde el usuario se encuentre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolverlo agregando el routerlink en el nodo donde se crea el arbol

```
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle routerLink="{{node?.path}}" routerLinkActive="viewActive">
          <mat-nav-list>
            <mat-list-item>
          <li class="mat-tree-node">

            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
            {{node.name}}
          </li>
            </mat-list-item>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-tree-node>
```

la clase `viewActive` se le aplican los estilos de css, el `node.path` es la url que se la agregue como propiedad a la interfaz del objeto que crea el arbol.